# How to use two countif in same formula to calculate in different docs?

Tags: countif

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzXqN.jpg)

I have two documents (`teste1` and `teste2`) with 2 lists of fruits in case, and I want to identify all repeated, within the 2 files.

I want to mark all the duplicates in column B with "R" as in the example. I've already tried the formulas in the image but I can't get them to consider both documents. What am I doing wrong?